# Can you extend a list when a list or button inside the list is pressed? CSS

Tags: html, css, list

So I'm pretty new to programming especially CSS, HTML, Javascript, etc. I made an Info Test website for myself and I made the following list, in which I have sub Topics, each subtopic is a list as well. My Problem now is that I shortened the first list so that every subpoint fits in perfectly, but when I extend the Subtopic lists, the list in which the subtopics are don't extend, and some of the text in the sublists get cut off. My question now is if I can extend the top list so that when I extend the sublists my text won't get cut off, but I only want the list to be extended when the sublists are opened. Is that possible in CSS?

**CSS and HTML**

```css
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: default;
}

.romanOne {
  font-family: timesnewroman;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: 64px;
  text-align: left;
}

.romanTwo {
  font-family: timesnewroman;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: auto;
}

.romanThree {
  font-family: timesnewroman;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: auto;
}

.FontFormatHeading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.FontFormat {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: -20px auto 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.FontFormat li {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.FontFormat li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.4);
}

.FontFormat li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.3);
}

.FontFormat li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background: #212121;
}

.AttributeHeading {
  font-size: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

.AttributeFormat {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: -20px auto 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.AttributeFormat li {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.AttributeFormat li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.4);
}

.AttributeFormat li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.3);
}

.AttributeFormat .AttributeList:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.AttributeSubList:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

.StyleOne {
  margin-left: 128px;
}

#StyleOneHeading {
  font-family: Arial;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.StyleOneJS:not([open]) {
  height: 37px;
}

.StyleOneJS[open] {
  height: 76px;
}

.StyleTwo {
  margin-left: 110px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

#StyleTwoHeading {
  font-family: Arial;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.StyleTwo details:not([open]) {
  height: 37px;
}

.StyleTwo details[open] {
  height: 76px;
}

details {
  transition: height 0.4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.DropDown1>summary {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 274px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.DropDown1:not([open]) {
  height: 37px;
}

.DropDown1[open] {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>First Web Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p class="AttributeHeading">Attribute</p>

  <div>
    <ul class="AttributeFormat">
      <!-- Style Attribute-->
      <li class="AttributeList">
        <details class="DropDown1" open>
          <summary>Style</summary>
          <ul class="romanOne">
            <li class="AttributeSubList">
              <div class="StyleOne">
                <details class="StyleOneJS">
                  <summary id="StyleOneHeading">Text größe wechseln</summary>
                  <br>
                  <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <span style=color:orange;>style</span>
                    <span>=</span>
                    <span style=color:limegreen;>font-size:32px</span>
                  </div>
                </details>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="AttributeSubList">
              <div class="StyleTwo">
                <details>
                  <summary id="StyleTwoHeading"> Text schriftart wechseln</summary>
                  <br>
                  <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <span style=color:orange;>style</span>
                    <span>=</span>
                    <span style=color:limegreen;>font-family:arial</span>
                  </div>
                </details>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="AttributeSubList">
              <span style=font-family:arial;>Filler Text</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>

      <li class="AttributeList">
        <details class="DropDown2">
          <summary>Filler Categories</summary>
          <ul class="romanTwo">
            <li class="AttributeSubList">
              <span style=font-family:arial>Filler Text</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>

      <li class="AttributeList">
        <details class="DropDown3">
          <summary>Filler Categories</summary>
          <ul class="romanThree">
            <li>
              <span style=font-family:arial>Filler Text</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```